# A dot in the linux username causes: "Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported."

Tags: sudo

I have a correctly working Debian server. All existing users who have been granted `sudo` rights can utilize `sudo` without any problems. However, a new user with a username that has a **dot** in it sees "Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported" when attempting to `sudo`.

I don't see any steps that were missed for this user. Here are my steps:

Create a privileged user with a dot in the username. I use this little script to add developer user accounts.

```
#!/bin/bash
uu=$1
useradd -m -G sudo,webdev -s /bin/bash $uu
passwd $uu
cd /home/$uu/
mkdir .ssh/
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 .ssh/
chown -R $uu:$uu .ssh/
ls -la .ssh/
cat $uu.pub > /home/$uu/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo "finished"
```

Check that user is in the sudo group:

```
getent group sudo
```

This already exists in `/etc/sudoers`

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Next I made /etc/sudoers.d/user.name (and set permissions to 640):

```
nano /etc/sudoers.d/user.name
user.name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

To test, log in with the user account and try to `sudo`. I get the above error.

One way I was able to resolve this was by adding this user to a different group that has sudo rights.

Either I am missing something, or the dot in the username is causing a problem that is not experienced with the other usernames.

Comment: Were you already logged in as `user.name` before you added them to the group?  You need to logout/login if you change groups.  I just tried this on a Centos7 machine and it worked: `-sh-4.2$ id -a
uid=1000(test.user) gid=1000(sudo) groups=1000(sudo)
-sh-4.2$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
`.  What Debian version are you using?  Also be aware of any local caching of groups or similar.

Comment: @StephenHarris - I made sure the user was logged out, then I tested with `su user.name`. Tested multiple times. Implented work-around, problem went away. Reverted my work-around, problem came back.

Comment: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers "sudo will read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, **skipping file names that** end in ‘`~`’ or **contain a ‘`.`’ character** ..."

Comment: I just did an equivalent test on Debian 10 (Buster)  `$ id
uid=2000(test.user) gid=2000(sudo) groups=2000(sudo)
$ sudo id
[sudo] password for test.user: 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ 
`.

Comment: @StephenHarris - are you using my exact steps (including the file in /etc/sudoers.d/test.user)? The link user `muru` posted above seems to indicate that the dot does indeed cause an issue.

Comment: The dot in the username doesn't cause the issue. It's because you chose to put the `sudo` configuration in a file whose name contains a dot.

Comment: @roaima True. But obviously I did not know that until user `muru` gave his comment above. That's the answer to my question. I'll accept it if `muru`  posts it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was given in a comment by [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru).

> sudo will read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end in ‘~’ or contain a ‘.’ character ...

- [Including other files from within sudoers](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers)

As roaima pointed out in another comment:

> The dot in the username doesn't cause the issue. It's because you chose to put the sudo configuration in a file whose name contains a dot.

That was exactly the issue. And the solution, which I veriifed, was just:

```
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/user.name /etc/sudoers.d/username
```